# Alt attribute as a variable in php

Tags: php, image, echo, alt

Having trouble calling up table names row as a Alt attribute

```
 $Linkimg = $row['Linkimg'];
 $Name = $row['Name'];

       if ($i==0) {
                   echo "<tr>\n";
                  }
echo "<td align='center' width='60'>" ;
echo "<img src=\"{$row['Linkimg']}\" alt=\"{$row['Name']}\>" ."</td>";
```

what am I missing those darn brackets

Answer (score 0):

It's safer to do this:

```
if($i===0) { ?>
    <tr>
<?php   } ?>
        <td>
            <img src="<?php echo $LinkImg; ?>" alt="<?php echo $Name; ?>"/>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "<img src=\"{$row['Linkimg']}\" alt=\"{$row['Name']}\">" . "</td>";
```